# SourceTree Graph Interpretation

Tags: git, graph, branch, atlassian-sourcetree

I am following a YouTube tutorial ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Igmh2hNIGM ) as a starter for SourceTree . As a part of the tutorial (at 15 min ) there is the attached graph which I cannot interpret it. I guess it is related to the sequence of the branches and how they are created from each other but not sure. Please help me out. Thanks a lot.

Here is the screenshot:
[image: The SourceTree Graph]

Comment: Your static image shows no graph, and going to the linked video and scanning forward to the 15 minute mark, I see no graph there either. Do you have the wrong snapshot and time here in your question?

Comment: Yep, I agree with you, this is not really a graph. But if you look carefully right beneath "All Branched" tab is says "Graph". Also the instructor call this "graphical" ( @ 15:22) .

Comment: There's nothing *in* that field: it's a big empty space. The tabs listed below the word `graph` are just various names (branch names and remote-tracking names); after that, there's that big empty space.

Comment: I think you are correct @torek,There is no graph. I will close this ticket. Thanks.

Comment: @torek : I juts don't know how to close the ticket or upvote your comments. Is it a side effect of being newbie to stackoverflow?

Comment: probably. In my browser, there's a little up-arrow next to each comment that I can click on to upvote the comment, and under the question itself, there are four selectable words, "Share Edit Follow Close Flag", that have pop-up text describing them. To close your own question you'd click on the "Close" word. Some things require some amount of reputation first though, and it's been many years and I'm not sure how much rep is needed for what...